# how to start navigating underwater

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I trying to build an AUV based on ROS and I am wondering whether there is beneficial tools that already available that I can use, for example there is the navigation stack for indoor autonomous wheeled robot navigation.

is there any similar tools for underwater robots ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294856/how-to-start-navigating-underwater/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I found an interesting post on the Moveit! blog about integration with an AUV :

http://moveit.ros.org/moveit!/ros/2015/07/02/going-underwater.html

You could probably integrate Moveit!  with the UUV simulator based on Gazebo :

https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator

They have a lot of documentation, with already integrated AUV, you could design your own based on the code of these pre-existing AUV

Also, there is a community within ROS Discourse that talk about AUV and maritime robotics in general:

https://discourse.ros.org/c/maritime

They can probably help a lot.

But I didn't found any of-the-shelf project that you could use (But that doesn't mean it doesn't exist)

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on 2018-06-23**:
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

if you are insterested in AUV models you can check two repositories that are complementary to the UUV Simulator

- https://github.com/uuvsimulator/eca_a9
- https://github.com/uuvsimulator/lauv_gazebo

I will be adding new tutorials to the documentation soon, but feel free to add questions in the issues page.

---

Originally posted by [Musa Marcusso](https://answers.ros.org/users/32182/musa-marcusso/) with karma: 81 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1